# The topological space of a schemes $X$ over $S$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a scheme of finite type over an algebraically closed field $k$. Then the topological space of $X$ is comprised of all $k$-points, i.e all morphism $\operatorname{Spec} k \to X$.

Now suppose that $X$ is a scheme over $S$. I am trying to recover the topological space $|X|$ of $X$ from the functor of points interpretation of $X$, that is what schemes fits into the following equality $|X|= \operatorname{Hom}_{Sch}(?, X)$?

Comment: It is actually not true that the points of $X$ are all $k$-valued. What is true is that if $X$ is of finite type over $k$, and $k$ is algebraically closed, then the *closed* points are in 1-1 correspondence with morphisms $\text{Spec }k \to X$. But if $k = \mathbb{R}$, and $X = \mathbb{A}^1_\mathbb{R} = \text{Spec }(\mathbb{R}[x])$, then the maximal ideal $(x^2 - 1)$ does not a admit a $\mathbb{R}$-valued point.

Comment: But would the topological space of $X$ be then the set of all $\mathbb{R}$-points ?

Comment: No. The topological space of $\text{Spec}(\mathbb{R}[x])$ is the set of all prime ideals of $\mathbb{R}[x]$, endowed with the Zariski topology. You cannot have a morphism $\text{Spec}(\mathbb{R}) \to \text{Spec}(\mathbb{R}[x])$ which hits the prime ideal $(x^2 + 1)$, because that would correspond to a ring homomorphism $\mathbb{R}[x] \to \mathbb{R}$, whose kernel is $(x^2 + 1)$. But then the image is isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}$, i.e. contains an element $y$ such that $y^2 = - 1$. Such an element does not exist in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: A minor correction: $(x^2+1)$, not $(x^2-1)$. But these comments are a very good explanation.

Comment: And even in the case of $k = \mathbb{C}$, not all points in $X$ must admit a $k$-valued point. For example the prime ideal $(0) \subset k[x]$. Because otherwise there would be an *injective* homomorphism of $k$-algebras $k[x] \to k$, so $k$ contained an element, transzendent over itself (the image of $x$). This is absurd.

Comment: @KReiser Of course :D

Answer (score 0):

If you're just interested in the underlying set $X$ then you can consider the following generalization of the $k$-points construction. Let us say that two maps $\mathrm{Spec}(K_1)\to X$ and $\mathrm{Spec}(K_2)\to X$ where $K_i$ are fields are called *equivalent* if there exists a third field $L$ and maps $K_i\to L$ such that the compositions $\mathrm{Spec}(L)\to\mathrm{Spec}(K_i)\to X$ agree. Then, you can form the set $\{\mathrm{Spec}(K)\to X\}/\sim$ where $K$ ranges over all fields. This set can be identified with the underlying set of $X$ as a topological space.